# Punctuation: in five countries; namely, Ireland, Italy, Spain, Sweden and Turkey

Tags: punctuation, semicolons

Is the punctuation of this sentence correct?

> The table given illustrates the expenditure on various products in five countries; namely, Ireland, Italy, Spain, Sweden and Turkey.

Is the usage of a semicolon before and a comma after 'namely' correct? Because until now and even after reading lots of tips about semicolons still I get confused whether to use them or not?

Comment: I'm not a writer, but I imagine this is a matter of style guides. I would use: "The table given illustrates the expenditure on various products in five countries, namely: Ireland, Italy, Spain, Sweden and Turkey."

Comment: @user3169 -- Your comment could be the core of a good answer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the "; namely," in the example sentence is correct.  The portion of the sentence starting with "namely" cannot stand as a complete sentence on its own.  (".  Namely," would be incorrect.)

I would replace the "; namely," with ":  " (A colon followed by two spaces.)  This ":  " introduces a list.  I think "namely," is redundant after such a colon.

The two parts of this sentence should be joined by either a semicolon, an emdash, or a colon.  As discussed, a colon would be redundant with "namely".  Thus, a semicolon is a reasonable choice.

The comma after "namely" is natural, but optional.

I use the "Oxford comma", so I would change "Sweden and" to "Sweden, and".  Some style guides insist on the Oxford comma; other style guides refuse to allow the Oxford comma.